# Problems getting rid of multiple periods in a FileName

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to take file names that look like: 
MAX_1.01.01.03.pdf  look like  Max_1010103.pdf.

Currently I have this code:

```
public void Sanitizer(List<string> paths)
{
  string regPattern = (@"[~#&!%+{}]+");
  string replacement = " ";

  Regex regExPattern = new Regex(regPattern);
  Regex regExPattern2 = new Regex(@"\s{2,}");
  Regex regExPattern3 = new Regex(@"\.(?=.*\.)");
  string replace = "";

  var filesCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

  try
  {
    foreach (string files2 in paths)
    {
      string filenameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(files2);
      string pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(files2);
      string sanitizedFileName = regExPattern.Replace(filenameOnly, replacement);
      sanitizedFileName = regExPattern2.Replace(sanitizedFileName, replacement);
      string sanitized = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathOnly, sanitizedFileName);

      if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sanitized))
      {
        DataGridViewRow clean = new DataGridViewRow();
        clean.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
        clean.Cells[0].Value = pathOnly;
        clean.Cells[1].Value = filenameOnly;
        clean.Cells[2].Value = sanitizedFileName;

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(clean);
        System.IO.File.Move(files2, sanitized);
      }
      else 
      {
        if (filesCount.ContainsKey(sanitized))
        {
          filesCount[sanitized]++;
        }
        else
        {
          filesCount.Add(sanitized, 1);
          string newFileName = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
              System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sanitized),
              filesCount[sanitized].ToString(),
              System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sanitized));

          string newFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
              System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(sanitized), newFileName);
          newFileName = regExPattern2.Replace(newFileName, replacement);
          System.IO.File.Move(files2, newFilePath);
          sanitized = newFileName;

          DataGridViewRow clean = new DataGridViewRow();
          clean.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
          clean.Cells[0].Value = pathOnly;
          clean.Cells[1].Value = filenameOnly;
          clean.Cells[2].Value = newFileName;

          dataGridView1.Rows.Add(clean);
        }

//HERE IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO GET RID OF DOUBLE PERIODS//
        if (regExPattern3.IsMatch(files2))
        {
          string filewithDoublePName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(files2);
          string doublepPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(files2);
          string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files2);
          string newName = name.Replace(".", "");
          string filesDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(files2);
          string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(files2);
          string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filesDir, newName+fileExt);

          DataGridViewRow clean = new DataGridViewRow();
          clean.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
          clean.Cells[0].Value =doublepPath;
          clean.Cells[1].Value = filewithDoublePName;
          clean.Cells[2].Value = newName;
          dataGridView1.Rows.Add(clean);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      throw;
      //errors.Write(e);
    }
  }
```

I ran this and instead of getting rid of ALL period (minus the period before a file extension), I get results like:  `MAX_1.0103.pdf`

If there are multiple periods like:  `Test....1.txt` I get these results:  `Test...1.txt`

It seems to only get rid of ONE period.  I am pretty new to Regular Expressions and it is a REQUIREMENT for this project.  Can anybody help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

EDITED to show changes made in code

Comment: Why not just keep the first period from the back? I don't know how to write it in c# but it'd be something like: s/(\.(?!\w+$))//g Look for dots where the look ahead can't find words + end of file. Everything that matches should get replaced to nothing. (Also don't know if c# supports negative lookahead :/)

Comment: Why is Regular Expressions a requirement for this project? Just because you *can* do something with a RegEx doesn't mean you *should*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not use the [`Path` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods.aspx):

```
string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(yourPath);
string newName = name.Replace(".", "");
string newPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(yourPath),
                              newName + Path.GetExtension(yourPath));
```

Each step separated for clarity.

So for the input

> "C:\Users\Fred\MAX_1.01.01.03.pdf"

I get the output

> "C:\Users\Fred\MAX_1010103.pdf"

which is what I'd expect.

If I supply:

> "C:\Users\Fred.Flintstone\MAX_1.01.01.03.pdf"

I get:

> "C:\Users\Fred.Flintstone\MAX_1010103.pdf"

again what I expect as I'm not processing the "DirectoryName" part of the path.

**NOTE** I missed the bit about RegEx being a REQUIREMENT. Still sticking by this answer though.

Comment: would this take care of ALL instances of a period in a filename?  What if i have something like Test.......1.txt?

Comment: @yeahumok - yes - "Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character or String in the current string are replaced with another specified Unicode character or String." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx

Comment: hmm this is so odd.  i implemented this in my code...however i keep getting some results that still contain periods.  I have edited my code--am i doing something wrong here?!

Comment: @yeahumok - where are the periods? What are the values before and after the various calls? What's your exact input string?

Answer (score 2):

Say, didn't you [already ask this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268325/getting-rid-of-multiple-periods-in-a-filename-using-regex/3268573)?

Anyway, I stick by [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268325/getting-rid-of-multiple-periods-in-a-filename-using-regex/3268573#3268573):

```
string RemovePeriodsFromFilename(string fullPath)
{
    string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
    string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
    string sanitized = filename.Replace(".", string.Empty);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);

    return Path.Combine(dir, sanitized + ext);
}
```

Now, since you specified that you **must** use RegEx, I suppose you could always *force* it in there:

```
string RemovePeriodsFromFilename(string fullPath)
{
    string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
    string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);

    // Look! Now the solution uses RegEx!
    string sanitized = Regex.Replace(filename, @"\.", string.Empty);

    string ext = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);

    return Path.Combine(dir, sanitized + ext);
}
```

Note: This is basically the exact same approach that [ChrisF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292043/problems-getting-rid-of-multiple-periods-in-a-filename/3292086#3292086) suggested.

Whoever is requiring that you use RegEx, I suggest you request an explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

I'd forgo regexes all together, do it like this:

1. Replace all periods with empty
   strings
2. Replace the last 3
   characters with ("."+Last 3
   characters)

Comment: doesn't work for extensions with more or less than 3 chars, e.g. ".html"

Answer (score 0):

This regex will remove all periods except for the period before the 3 or 4 letter extension.

```
string filename = "test.test......t.test.pdf";    
string newFilename = new Regex(@"\.(?!(\w{3,4}$))").Replace(filename, "");
```

If you want it to work with 2 letter extensions just change the {3,4} to {2,4}

Good luck!

Comment: ...or just use `\.(?!([^.]+$))`

Comment: I did consider that, however what if the user is using MacOSX and uploads a file without an extension? example: Snicker.Doodles ? The resulting file name should be SnickerDoodles !

Comment: Although I guess you have extensions like .compiled, .library, and .torrent - in which case your regex would be better!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this, maybe:

```
string fileName = "MAX_1.01.01.03.pdf";
fileName = fileName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + fileName.Substring(1).ToLower();
fileName = fileName.Replace(".", "");
```